# Apache Flink writeAsCsv is having no content.

Tags: java, apache-flink

Im trying to save my datastream in a csv as a tuple of two Long values (an appearance timestamp and system timestamp). I am creating the DataStream of Tuple values as follows.

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, Long>> csvStream  = messageStream.map(new MapFunction<GraphStreamItem, Tuple2<Long, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Long, Long> map(GraphStreamItem graphStreamItem) throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(graphStreamItem.getAppTimestamp(), graphStreamItem.getSysTimestamp());
        }
    });
```

Now I am trying to save it as csv as follows:

```
csvStream.writeAsCsv("path/to/save.csv", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE).setParallelism(1);
```

But the csv file seems to blank always. I tried printing csvStream and the two tuple values are visible when i do that. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Can you try with `writeAsText` and check?

Comment: writeAsText works. I initially had it writing to text. Now since i wanted to analyse the data, having it as csv makes it easier for me it to import into some other tool for the purpose. Thats why i was so confused.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
csvStream.setParallelism(1).writeAsCsv(
  "path/to/save.csv", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE); 
env.execute()
```